# how to use font awsome as a marker in react leaflet when click on map?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, react-leaflet

I use react-leaflet package and I need to add custom font awsome when user click on point of map.like when a place is metro, icon become metro icon and so on.
I mean user select icon when click on map, or add an icon when click on map.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this maybe?

```
import { Marker } from "react-leaflet";
import { divIcon } from "leaflet";
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from "react-dom/server";

class MyCustomMarker extends React.Component {

  generateMarkerContent = fontAwesomeConfig => {
    const { fontAwesomeConfig } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="my-custom-icon-content">
        {/* Render based on the font awesome config here */}
      </div>
    );
  };

  render(){
    const icon = divIcon({
      className: "my-custom-icon",
      iconSize:[24, 24],
      html: return renderToStaticMarkup(this.generateMarkerContent(t))
    });

    return (
      <Marker {...this.props} icon={icon} />
    )
  }
}
```